# internal error app engine endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine

So I created an App Engine Connected Android app in Eclipse and deployed fine. Sample code works fine too.

But now I want to add new Endpoints. I create them, add @Api tag, methods, and call them from Javascript and Android.

Works fine when I call on locally deployed server, but not when calling the deployed app engine.

Basically I get just "Internal Error" and there's nothing in the app engine log, except a note that the api method was called.

So two questions:

1) Why does it work locally but not on app engine. All the method does is return a hard coded list of strings.

2) More generally, how to get more information when getting Internal Error?

Hard to debug app engine errors, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I had also strange errors with endpoints and debugging is indeed very hard. I relised you must follow a couple of rules, namely:

- Your api and method names can't use "_", so **@Api(name="my_api")** is wrong and **@Api(name="myApi")** is right.
- Your api methods mustn't return simple types, so return a **String** is wrong, but return **MyString** is right. Your method can also return **void**.

An example of a custom endpoint should look like this:

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;

@Api(name="myApi",
     path="my_api")
public class MyEndpoint {

    @ApiMethod (name="myMethod", 
                path="my_method",
                method="httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST")
    public MyCustomObject myMethod () {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that all the annotation attributes are optional.